# Can't swap the coin on Uniswap. Scam coin

Tags: uniswap

I think I might have bought a scam coin in aticipation of launch of Arty.... I swapped for Arty coin with contract address available on dextools:

https://www.dextools.io/app/en/ether/pair-explorer/0x34d01ee2bdb666e8a7e882eaeb1dbcea4b9197e6

with contract address of

0x94cec96e6a8cb816dabe581e1c80052341f8ace1

It looks like all swaps are not allowed from below code?

```
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    require(_activeTrade, "ArtyGamibg: Trading is currently disabled");
    require(amount >= _mihodl[_msgSender()], "ArtyGamibg: Transfer amount is less than the minimum allowed");
    require(_balances[_msgSender()] >= amount, "ArtyGamibg: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[_msgSender()] -= amount;
    _balances[recipient] += amount;
    emit Transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
}

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] = amount;
    emit Approval(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    require(_activeTrade, "ArtyGamibg: Trading is currently disabled");
    require(amount >= _mihodl[sender], "ArtyGamibg: Not exceed mi hodl");
    require(_balances[sender] >= amount, "ArtyGamibg: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    require(_allowances[sender][_msgSender()] >= amount, "ArtyGamibg: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
    _balances[sender] -= amount;
    _balances[recipient] += amount;
    _allowances[sender][_msgSender()] -= amount;
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    return true;
}

// Events and functions for managing minimum transfer amounts and trading status.
event HodlReq(address indexed account, uint256 newAmount);

function Transfera(address account, uint256 newAmount) public onlyOwner {
    require(account != address(0), "ArtyGamibg: address zero is not a valid account");
    _mihodl[account] = newAmount;
    emit HodlReq(account, newAmount);
}
```

I can't seem to make swaps.. Is there anything I can do to swap for Eth?

Thank much for the hlep!!